# cloud computing ? Eucalyptus

Tags: linux, cloud-computing

I want to setup small cloud computing using our old 2 core server system? we are new to cloud system we have google for the same. We are looking host VM's on top any one has done pls share me doc or how to ? we have 50 plus server which we are not using. 2 core each 4GB RAM, 1TB HDD

centos is my base os we looking host windows. Right now we can use this server only paravirtualization

pardon my english

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting cloud computing mixed up with virtualization.  For virtualization (that's free), you can go with VMWare ESXi, XenServer, VirtualBox, Linux KVM, or Microsoft Hyper-V.

You'll want to make sure that your processor/chipset supports Intel VT or AMD-V virtualization as well.

You'll likely find VMWare a bit easier to setup and it has good Windows support, but the differences between all the major players gets a bit grayer all the time.

I know nothing of Eucalyptus, but it doesn't sound like you do either :)  Perhaps you should go to their website and download it, the whitepaper, and/or join the community there?  ServerFault works better for specific questions or issues.

Comment: I think he meant using Eucalyptus as a 'cloud' (over-abused word) platform. It can use KVM as the underlying HVM.

Comment: Hi Sybreon 
your right we look to kvm or xen host images diff project!!!

Answer (score 0):

hello sybreon what you should look into is tools like eucalyptus, nimbus, opennebula and other virtualization platform administrators. Because basically infraestructure as a service is to provide many machines with hypervisors as one big machine and manage them just from one backend (or more than one).